# Why does opening of the Ca-channels trigger the release of neurotransmitters?

Tags: molecular-biology

I understand that the opening of the Calcium channels trigger the release of stored neurotransmitter in granules, but what is it about the flow of positive ions that makes the vesicles fuse with the cell membrane? Does the vesicle itself carry a charge or concentration gradient?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For example, have you looked at the related [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/health-and-medicine/nervous-system-and-sensory-infor/neural-cells-and-neurotransmitters/v/neurotransmitter-release) material? ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: I am not sure if this response is autogenerated, but I don't see how my question does not follow the guidelines. Synaptotagmin is not mentioned in any explainations I have read about action potential.

Comment: You'll note I didn't downvote (or flag) your question and I'm not claiming your question violates the guidelines. This was just intended as friendly encouragement to do some research on your own since this information is readily available online. ——— For example, when I did a search with keywords from your question ("neurotransmitter release calcium") one of the top hits was the Khan Academy video I linked to, another was [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3249630/), which does include details of the molecular mechanism ...

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Synaptotagmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptotagmin) is a protein that is part of the synaptic release machinery. It binds calcium specifically, which leads to a conformational change that encourages vesicle fusion with the membrane, therefore the ultimate release mechanism is not via voltage or charge but by calcium itself.